# reactJS renders <select> options larger than everything else in the view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `<select>` in a reactJS application.  It is generated with this code:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-12 text_15">
        <select value={this.state.securityQuestion} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="0">What is you mother's maiden name?</option>
            <option value="1">What elementary school did you attend?</option>
            <option value="2">What was the name of your first pet?</option>
            <option value="3">What city were you born in?</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I render the page in Chrome (with developer tools displayed) the page looks like this:

[image]

When I click on the dropdown arrow, the options get displayed but they are way to large:

[image]

My .css file has text_15 defined as this:

```
  .text_15 {   
       font: 15px 'Ariel',  Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
```

How do I size the dropdown list to be the same size as what is rendered in the first image I provided (with the value what is your mothers maiden name)?

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the text size of the other text?

Comment: Is this only in one particular browser? It has to be comming from some styling that you've got in somewhere, as react doesn't by default come with any styling that targets dropdown lists.

Comment: @FelixKling the line that displays "Select one of the following questions to answer is rendered with <div className="col-12 test-left text_15"><label>Select one of the following questions to answer</label></div>

Comment: But what’s the size of the other text (before/after)? I guess my question is: which text shown is actually 15px?

Comment: @FelixKling all text on the page is rendered with text_15.  But as Marc Randall suggested, I looked at the rendering with Microsoft Edge and the dropdown displays as I had expected so I guess I have some kind of issue with Chrome.

Comment: @MarcRandall I checked with Microsoft Edge and it rendered correctly.  I guess I have to do some research on Chrome issues and how Chrome renders the <option> elements.  Thanks!